# Localize numbers in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to parse some numbers in such a way:

1 -> "One",
2 -> "Two",
etc.

I need those strings localized for different languages. Is there any tool that makes such a parsing?

Comment: you can use a simple map like {1: {'en':'one', 'bn': 'other1'},2: {'en':'two', 'bn': 'other2'},}
access 1 like data[1]['bn']

Comment: @towhid Thanks, but I know how to implement it manually. I wonder if there is a general Dart or Flutter solution with numbers already translated (since it is a pretty common thing). Something like: FlutterLocalizations.localizedStringFromNumber(1);

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `intl` package https://pub.dev/packages/intl. There is a function `Intl.select`. I think it can helps.